# Issue with select box show selected value from database in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine-plugins

I have a ruby string like

```
@t3= ["", "Overview", "<span>Risks</span>", "<span>Scrumbler</span>", "Roadmap"]
```

return from the database
i want to get it into the array but it doesnot get it as array

I try to dp the following but it doesnot work.

```
<% @t=@t3.tr('[]', '').split(',').map(&:to_s) %>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How is `["", "Overview", "Risks", "Scrumbler", "Roadmap"]`  a string?

Comment: What is `@menu` and what does `@menu.menu_list` return? And what is your expected result / output?

Comment: @surya Its is return from the database so it is work as string i am also stcuk that how its is string

Comment: @Stefan SOrry for typo.. i update the questions

Comment: What is the query that you used to fetch this data? Could you please post that code as well?

Comment: Yes sure.
Menu.joins('LEFT JOIN projects ON projects.id = menus.project_id').where("menus.project_id = ? AND menus.menu_name = ?", @project.id,'Admin').first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I solved it by using.

```
<% @t=@t3.tr('[]', '').split(',').map! {|item| item.to_s.strip } %>
```

Thanks